# Find all prime numbers $p$ such that $p \mid 2^p + 1$

Tags: number-theory

I know that they somehow look like Mersenne primes $2^p-1$ but in this case we have $2^p+1$.

Here is my attempt.

If $p \mid 2^p+1$ then $ \exists k \in Z$ such that $pk = 2^p+1$ or that $2^p \equiv -1 \pmod p$.
 For example, $2$ is a prime but it doesn't divide $2^2 + 1 = 5$. However, $3$ is a prime that divides $2^3 + 1 = 9$

Now how can I generate all numbers that satisfy this ?

Comment: I just edited $2^3+1=\cdots$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using Fermat's little theorem $p$ divides $2^p-2$ and if we add your hypothesis $p|2^p+1$ then $p$ divides $3=(2^p+1)-(2^p-2)$

Comment: So by fermats we have $2^p\equiv 2 \pmod p$ and so $p \mid 2^p - 2$ . Now what do you mean that if i add my hypothesis we get $p$ divides $3$ ???   Does this mean $p=3$ is the only solution !

Comment: $p=3$ is the only solution

Comment: Ohhhhh, I got it. So since $p \mid 2^p -2$ and $p \mid 2^p + 1$ then $p$ divides any linear combination of $2^p + 1$ and $2^p-1$. In particular, $p$ divides $2^p +1 -2^p + 2 = 3$ and hence $p \mid 3 $

Comment: Now what if want to find all primes that divides $2^p - 1$ Then If I used fermats little theorem again then I would have that $p \mid 2^p -2$ and $p \mid 2^p -1$ then $p \mid 2^p -1 - 2^p -2$ then $p \mid 1$  ? which means there are no primes that satisfy this condition so no primes exists for that ?

Comment: yes there is no prime that satisfy $p|2^p-1$

Answer (score 2):

Obviously if $p\mid 2^p+1$, then $2^{2p}\equiv 1\pmod p$ and hence order of the number $2$ modulo $p$ devides $2p$, and by fermat theorem devides also the number $p-1$ which means the order is $2$, because $(p,\frac{p-1}2)=1$. This means that $p=3$.